problem in get dependencies because of verson problem
D:\fluttur\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.
The current Dart SDK (3.3.4) only supports null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 65
any one help to solve this

You'll need a pre-3.0 dart to "dart migrate" this code to null-safety.  I have a video on how to do that using puro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olqmK-opexA
